# Issues installing Qgis on Mavericks (brew and regular install)

Tags: python, homebrew, osx-mavericks, qgis

I have been trying to install QGIS on Mavericks and I have failed. Prior to installing QGIS, I installed GDAL using homebrew. I also installed Numpy, SciPy and pyqt using the detailed instructions provided at: http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/

I modified my .bash_profile so that when I run echo `$PYTHONPATH`

I get `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:`

I tried first installing qgis running

`brew install qgis --with-grass --with-postgis`
and I get the error message

```
libtool: link: cannot determine absolute directory name of `@@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/libpng/1.5.17/lib'
make[3]: *** [libcairo.la] Error 1
make[2]: *** [install] Error 2
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2

READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/3526
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/23375
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/20522
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/23252
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/16361
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/18528`
```

Then I also tried downloading the QGIS dmg file from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis However, I get an error message each time I try opening Install QGIS.pkg saying that I need matplotlib that I already have!

Is anyone else also having problems installing QGIS on Mavericks? Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thank you